# Unhiding UIImageView not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, hidden, viewdidload

I initially hide the `UIImageView` in `viewDidLoad` function using this code:

```
_friendOneImage.hidden=YES;
_friendTwoImage.hidden=YES;
_friendThreeImage.hidden=YES;
_friendFourImage.hidden=YES;
_friendFiveImage.hidden=YES;
_friendSixImage.hidden=YES;
```

and now **in** **another function** I am unhiding it using this code:

```
_friendOneImage.hidden=NO;
_friendTwoImage.hidden=NO;
_friendThreeImage.hidden=NO;
_friendFourImage.hidden=NO;
_friendFiveImage.hidden=NO;
_friendSixImage.hidden=NO;
```

BUT THE **UNHIDING IS NOT WORKING** WHEREAS HIDING IS WORKING.

Please help.

Comment: Add/modify the question to include enough context of the declaration/scope of the `_friendOneImage` and the other `UIImageView`s. Off the top I suspect that `UIImage`s are nil in the second set of code.

Comment: check by putting break point in the function that is called or not.

Comment: can u show the method and viewdidLoad method also and one ? r u hided the image in any other place on the view

Comment: @Indrajeet : Yes I checked that. Function is being called and evan hidden=NO is also being executed perfectly but there is no output.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: No, I am only hiding the UIImageView inside viewDidLoad.

Comment: can u send ur project to my mail id karthik.saral@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The image was not set that is why I was facing that problem. I just setted the image and its being shown now.

Thank you.